# Interfacing MAX6675 with Arduino Mega 2560

Tags: arduino-mega, spi, max6675

I'm trying to use a thermocouple k type and a MAX6675 IC.  I bought the MAX6675 chip and made the circuit (just a 1 nf capacitor on +5 V and GND near the IC) with the help of the [datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX6675.pdf)

I used the library from [adafruit](https://github.com/adafruit/MAX6675-library) and for the sake of avoiding errors, I used the Example from the same library (serialThermocouple) with 52 as CLK, pin 50 as SDO and pin 53 as CS.

The program is producing numbers and the sensor appears to stabilize around 104.0C and 105.0C, but why? that is not the real temp or even close to it? Is there any other conversion to get the real degree around me?

**oh !! and Another question..** 
Why is the 8 bit shift here?

```cpp
  v = spiread();
  v <<= 8;
  v |= spiread();
```

I saw it in many code. Also this one

```cpp
digitalWrite(_ssPin, LOW);
tcData = SPI.transfer(0x00)<<8;
tcData |= SPI.transfer(0x00);
digitalWrite(_ssPin, HIGH);
temp = (tcData>>3)/4.0;
```

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86238/discussion-on-question-by-rf3t-interfacing-max6675-with-arduino-mega-2560).